# Chat react native + firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, chat

Good morning community, I am trying to make an application that as a central axis has a group chat where people with the same tastes about something specific can talk.

I already have quite a part of the application polished, I have implemented the individual chat, but I have problems with the implementation of a group chat, that is, my problem is that the group would have to be obtained from firebase and I do not have so much experience in that. If someone could pass me some documentation to be able to assimilate the knowledge or some idea of ​​what I have to investigate it would be of great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a collection named **groupChat** and each document holds various details of each group chat like- name, createdDate,bannerImg,etc.. and create a [subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections) named **messages**  and each document in this subcollection represents the message by user for a particular group

Comment: I was trying to do what you say, what I do not quite understand is that when I need to use realtime and firestone

Comment: You can use both realtime database or firestore, but firestore is a better option for chat functionality